# Is there a way to password protect a file in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I was looking through some of the files of an application I downloaded and tried to view the contents of some of them, however, I was prompted to enter a password to the file which triggered me to ask how that was possible and how I could do it.

---

**Attempts**

1. I tried using the "`Encrypt contents to secure data`" option of file explorer and then changing the encryption key with `certmgr`, but it didn't work.
2. I tried seeing if there was a built-in windows zip folder password option but it seems that it was removed (I know that 7zip works but I mean its not the same)

So is there a way to password protect files?

---

<sup>I am using Windows 10 Pro Education with a KMS server</sup>

Comment: Does this help? https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000705.htm#:~:text=Select%20the%20file%20or%20folder,click%20OK%20on%20both%20windows.

Comment: It depends on the format and application.
A .zip file can easily be password protected if you use 7-Zip (as you already discovered).
Office files (e.g. Word .docx) can be password protected from within the Office application (though under the hood they are also .zip files).
But there is no operating system way to make a file password protected in a way that it keeps its extension and makes the operating system pop up the password. At least not in a way you can send over the internet. As @LisL mentioned there are ways to protect files/folders on your own disk.

Comment: @BrechtSanders this is what I initially thought too, however, the files I looked at begged to differ I guess you could say.

Comment: @Asian What type of files were they, which extension did they have?

Comment: It was a `dll` file